# Legend for x-axis categories in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to get custom legends below the chart where I can add my own text.

In the below example, I want to create legends for each violation codes. It would be static text describing the violation codes.
Is it possible ? If so, how can I achieve it ?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Staten Island Violation Code Destribution</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Staten Island Violation Distribution'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: NYC Open DataSet</a>'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        data: {
            csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Count'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: 'Count: <b>{point.y}</b>'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Violation Count',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                format: '{point.y}', // one decimal
                y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
                style: {
                    fontSize: '8px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="../../js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/modules/data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 300px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<pre id="csv" style="display:none">
VIOLATIONCODE,COUNT
10F,843
06D,603
02G,602
10B,583
08A,517
06C,472
02B,415
04L,405
04H,322
06E,317
04N,293
04A,283
06F,267
10H,262
Others,3335
</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it would help to have a more detail on what specifically you would like your custom legend text to be (e.g. based on some data in your series...?)

Comment: No. It is static text giving a description of the violation codes.

Comment: Could you attach a mockup, cause by [renderer text](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) you can also add custom text.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Something like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-negative) Each x-axis category will have a description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aligning each violation code within its own series and then defining the series titles will achieve what I think you're looking for.

```
<pre id="csv" style="display:none">
VIOLATIONCODE,Description1,Description2,Description3,Description4,Description5,Description6
10F,843
06D,,603
02G,,,602
10B,,,,583
08A,,,,,517
06C,,,,,,472
[...]
</pre>
```

Also move your `dataLabels` property into `plotOptions` and set `grouping` to false.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nxv9hkp4/)

Comment: If you prefer, you can set the series names from within the highcharts object instead: http://jsfiddle.net/nxv9hkp4/1/. Aside from that, I'm out of suggestions.